# Trouble Installing slurm on Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, slurm

When I run `slurmd`, it gives a `-bash: slurmd: command not found`.

I ran `sudo yum install slurm` to install slurm. I don't know why it isn't working, or if I installed all the required packages for slurm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package that you need is `slurm-slurmd`.

```
yum install slurm-slurmd

dnf install slurm-slurmd
```

That will provide the `slurmd` command which will be located at `/usr/bin/slurmd` and it will also provide the `slurmd` service.